# Передача значения элементу input, написанному с помощью react select

Tags: javascript

Пишу расширение Chrome для автоматизации заполнения форм на сайте. Столкнулся c такой проблемой: элемент *textarea* это обычное окно для ввода информации, в которое по идее можно передать любое значение value = 'text'. В окне появляется нужный текст, но после того как кликнуть в область этого окна мышкой, или произвести любое другое действие, текст исчезает. То есть значение попросту не сохраняется. Если же изначально сфокусировать окно ввода путем нажатия по нему курсором, и только после этого передать значение value, то все сработает.

Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему. Возможно есть способ выполнить клик по этому окну. Перепробовал все возможные способы клика, не получается. Подозреваю, что сайт написан на React

```
<div class="Textarea_Textarea__2qL3b Textarea_ResizeHorizontal__1DeEf shared_RowField__3BEY0 Textarea_TextareaInvalid__1F75c Textarea_TextareaAutoHeight__2vqgL">
 <textarea class="Textarea_Input__2rC0f" name="violations[2].note" style="height: 2.25rem;"></textarea>
</div>
```

[image: Иллюстрация]

Comment: Как именно передаете значение value = 'text'?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('Textarea_Input__2rC0f')[7].value = 'text'

Comment: Может на этом поле висит какой-то багированный javascript обработчик проверяющий ошибки ввода, срабатывающий на фокус. Поле чистое или на нем обработчики висят левые?